# Uniformalize vs uniformize

Tags: mathematics, dictionaries

In my standard college dictionary "uniformalize" is listed as *rare*, while "uniformize" is not listed at all, yet wikipedia is the opposite.

Comment: Both words sound ugly and manufactured to me.  How about "make uniform" ?

Answer (score 4):

A more common single-word term (since this is a single word request) for what you mean (especially in programming and database work) is **normalize**, which means "to conform to a standard" or "to make the same".

Comment: "Standardize" might also be good.

Comment: @Hellion Oops! I completely forgot about that one. Maybe all the traumatic standardized tests I took in school forced me to block out the memories ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any pitfalls in resorting to Google Ngram evidence [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uniformalize%2Cuniformize&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuniformalize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuniformize%3B%2Cc0). 'Uniformize' seems far less uncommon (if still far from common).

Your question certainly does not fall in the 'can be simply and unequivocally answered by looking in a single commonly-available reference work' category! For these uncommon words, you can expect to see different pronouncements (on how commonly they are used, etc) by different dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Most online dictionaries give "uniform" as the verb meaning to bring something to uniformity. The full versions might add other, less used versions (for instance webster has uniformize).

In any case, uniformize is transformation to a verb of the noun uniform (probably disregarding the fact that a verb already existed, but could have happened the other way around as well)

Uniformalize creates a verb from the noun Uniformal, which is an archaic form of Uniform.

Basically if you're writing something yourself you should probably use "uniform"